# Windows Php Sybase libraries

Tags: php, sybase

I have to enable php_sybase extension in my windows-apache server, but i get an error maybe due to sybase dll depencencies.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\xampp\php\ext\php_sybase_ct.dll'
```

I'm sure ext folder and dll file exist, but i haven't got sybase driver. Where can i find sybase libreary to let php_sybase extenson work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the Sybase libraries, I'm pretty sure this used to be able to be a free downloaded from Sybase, but I found a copy at https://apps.state.or.us/tech/htdocs/sybase.html  or you can download the developer edition (which includes the client libraries) from http://www.sybase.com/ase_1500devel